# Using Horner's Method

Tags: polynomials, recursive-algorithms

I'm trying to evaluate a polynomial recursively using [Horner's method.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method)

It's rather simple when I have every value of $x$ (like: $x+x^2+x^3...$), but what if I'm missing some of those? Example: $-6+20x-10x^2+2x^4-7x^5+6x^7$.

I would also appreciate it if someone could explain the method in more detail, I've used the description [listed here](http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/hornermod.html) but would like some more explanation.

Comment: If you are missing terms, the corresponding coefficient to use in the method is 0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$6x^7-7x^5+2x^4-10x^2+20x-6$ =

$6x^7+0x^6-7x^5+2x^4+0x^3-10x^2+20x-6$

The method is essentially start with the coefficient of the highest power, multiply by $x$ and add the next coefficient. Stop when you add the constant coefficient.

So steps in the iteration go:

$6$

$6x[+0]$

$6x^2-7$

$6x^3-7x+2$

$6x^4-7x^2+2x[+0]$

$6x^5-7x^3+2x^2-10$

$6x^6-7x^4+2x^3-10x+20$

$6x^7-7x^5+2x^4-10x^2+20x-6$

Trust this helps

Answer (score 7):

Horner's method or form is also sometimes called nested form.  You can think of it as starting with the whole polynomial $$6x^7-7x^5+2x^4-10x^2+20x-6,$$ setting aside the constant term (if it's zero, you can set aside a zero here) and factoring out an $x$ from the remaining terms $$(6x^6-7x^4+2x^3-10x+20)x-6,$$ and then repeating the process for the innermost polynomial (the part that isn't yet fully in nested form:
$$((6x^5-7x^3+2x^2-10)x+20)x-6$$
$$(((6x^4-7x^2+2x)x-10)x+20)x-6$$
$$((((6x^3-7x+2)x+0)x-10)x+20)x-6$$
$$(((((6x^2-7)x+2)x+0)x-10)x+20)x-6$$
$$((((((6x)x-7)x+2)x+0)x-10)x+20)x-6$$
$$(((((((6)x+0)x-7)x+2)x+0)x-10)x+20)x-6$$

Alternately, if your polynomial is $$p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^k=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0,$$ you can think of $p(x)$ in nested form as $p_0$ where $p_n=a_n$ and $p_{k-1}=p_kx+a_{k-1}$.  That is, start with the leading coefficient ($a_n$).  Multiply by $x$ and add the next coefficient (adding zero to fill in for "missing" powers of $x$), repeating until you've added the constant term ($a_0$). Back to the same example:
$$\begin{align}
p_7&=6\\
p_6&=(6)x+0\\
p_5&=((6)x+0)x-7\\
p_4&=(((6)x+0)x-7)+2\\
p_3&=((((6)x+0)x-7)+2)x+0\\
p_2&=(((((6)x+0)x-7)+2)x+0)-10\\
p_1&=((((((6)x+0)x-7)+2)x+0)-10)+20\\
p_0&=(((((((6)x+0)x-7)+2)x+0)-10)+20)-6
\end{align}$$

Comment: I took the example from the original post. Your formatting echoes the link given, so I'm sure it will be useful.

Comment: @Mark: I just noticed that about the example (so just edited that line out of my answer)... apparently, I need to work on reading the original question better.

Answer (score 6):

You can also carry it out in a synthetic division table.  Suppose you want to evaluate $f(x) = x^4 - 3x^2 + x - 5$ for $x = 3$. Set up a table like this

```
              1    0     -3    1     5
          3
             -------------------------
              1
```

Now multiply the number on the bottom and total as follows.

```
              1    0     -3    1     5
          3        3
             -------------------------
              1    3
```

Work your way across in this manner.

```
              1    0     -3    1     -5
          3        3      9   18    57
             -------------------------
              1    3      6   19    52
```

We have $f(3) = 52$.  Let's run a check

$$ f(3) = 81 -3*9 + 3 - 5 = 54 - 2 = 52.$$
$$ f(3) = 54 - 2 = 52.$$

This is a clean, tabular way to see Horner's method work.

Comment: You have multiple typos; -5 in the table and 52 in the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the form by inspection, say $16x^6+8x^3+4x+2$,

1. with the terms in decreasing order, write the differences in exponents over the top. Those are going to be the powers of $x$ in the factorization.

[[image: <span class=]$$16x^6+8x^3+4x+2$$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ioPv.png)

2. process them from right to left by writing left parens equal to the number of exponent differences, followed by the first coefficient
   $$(((16$$
3. multiply by $x$ raised to the first exponent difference and add the next coefficient $$(((16x^3+8$$
4. add a closing paren, the next power of $x$ and the next coefficient $$(((16x^3+8)x^2+4$$
5. repeat $$((((16x^3+8)x^2+4)x+2$$

For the polynomial that you gave, $-6+20x-10x^2+2x^4-7x^5+6x^7$ we have exponent differences (powers) of $(2,1,2,1,1)$ and coefficients $(6,-7,2,-10,20,-6)$ (both written from high to low) so the steps look like this
$$(((((6$$
$$(((((6x^2-7$$
$$(((((6x^2-7)x+2$$
$$(((((6x^2-7)x+2)x^2-10$$
$$(((((6x^2-7)x+2)x^2-10)x+20$$
$$(((((6x^2-7)x+2)x^2-10)x+20)x-6$$
Writing it like this makes "finding where to start" easy because you just start at the first expression and (on a calculator) type `=` every time you hit a right parenthesis. It would go like this `6*x^2-7=*x+2=*x^2-10=*x+20=*x-6` (or you can use parentheses).